# How to tag EBS volume using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, amazon-ebs

I want to add name or tag property when adding/attaching a new EBS volume to EC2 instance, but I don't see ansible [ec2_vol](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vol_module.html) doing that. It only allows `name:` to attach existing EBS volume, not when creating new one. Probably there is other way around ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use the `ec2_tag` module after the volume has been created.

(See documentation here http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_tag_module.html )

You'll need the volume id, but the `ec2_vol` module returns that so you should be able to register the result.

The first example of the `ec2_tag` module shows tagging a volume

```
tasks:
- name: tag a resource
  ec2_tag: resource=vol-XXXXXX region=eu-west-1 state=present
  args:
    tags:
      Name: ubervol
      env: prod
```

Comment: great, how about naming the volume ? that would be great thanks.

Comment: The "name" of anything in ec2 is actually just a tag called "Name", so in the above example the volume would have the name "ubervol".